# How do you get to the page that describes reputation privileges you have earned?

Tags: support, reputation

The other day when I logged in I received a notification.  It said that I was now able to vote to close questions.  I have already had this privilege for awhile, but I clicked on the details link in the notification and it took me to a page that describes all the different privileges I have earned or have yet to earn along with their associated reputation requirements.

I have no idea how one would access this page from anywhere on the site itself.  I've looked through my user pages and such but can't find anything.  Is there a link somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is a new addition, but you can click on your reputation score at the top of the site and it brings you to the privileges page.

Comment: I feel privileged now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clicking your reputation is no longer sufficient with the advent of the new top bar.

Go to your user page, either by clicking yourself in the top bar or through any other means, then click the privileges link next to the profile edit link.

[image]